# how is possible that order of kernal of a group is more than 1

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Fundamental theorem of isomorphism says that if $\phi : G \to \bar G$ is a group homomorphism, then the mapping  $\bar\phi : G/\ker(\phi) \to \phi(G)$, deﬁned by $\bar\phi(g\ker(\phi)) = \phi(g)$, is an isomorphism. In other words, $G/\ker(\phi) \cong \phi(G)$

Now we know that  there are exactly $4$ homomorphisms from $Z_{20}$ onto $Z_{10}$ : there must be isomorphism between them according to theorem. For that order of $\ker(\phi)$ must be $2$ . But since by the property of homomorphism, an identity element gets mapped with identity, so all the elements of $\ker(\phi)$ must be identity element of $Z_{20}$ and they must be two at the same time we know identity element is unique.

Comment: Assuming $\phi(g)=h$, it is true that if $g$ equals the identity then $h$ equals the identity. But the converse is not true: if $h$ equals the identity, the element $g$ may or may not be equal to the identity.

Answer (score 1):

You ask how the kernel of a homomorphism can ever have more than one element.

Consider this example. Let $G$ and $H$ be groups. Define the map
$$
\phi: G\to H
$$
by
$$
\phi(g) = e_H.
$$
for all $g\in G$. That is, $\phi$ maps all elements in $G$ to the identity element in $H$. This is a homomorphism because
$$
\phi(g)\phi(h) = e_he_h = e_h = \phi(gh)
$$
for all $g,h\in G$. And for this map you have
$$
\ker\phi = \{g\in G: \phi(G) = e_h\} = G.
$$
Now if your homomorphism is injective (one-to-one) then indeed only the identity in $G$ maps to the identity in $H$. It is, in fact, true that a homomorphism is injective exactly when the kernel is trivial.

So, if you would more examples of homomorphisms that have non-trivial kernels, just look at examples of homomorphisms that are not injective.